# Php Generate buttons for each line of a table from database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to call database and a specific table, then display table values in rows and at the end of them have buttons 'edit' and 'delete' that allow me to edit that line or delete it completely.
At the moment I only manage to display the table and generate the buttons, but not 'tie' the buttons to that row.
I need to generate the buttons when displaying the table, and then 'tie' the buttons to corresponding row.

Edit:

```
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['show'])) {
    $sel = "SELECT id, vardas, pavarde, amzius, miestas FROM zmogaus_info";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            echo "Id: ".$row["id"]." ".$row["vardas"]." ".$row["pavarde"]." ".$row["amzius"]."m."."<input type='submit' name='".$row['id']."' value='Delete'>"."<br>";
        }
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST[$row['id']])){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM zmogaus_info WHERE id=".$row['id'];
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

I think the problem might be with the way I use $row['id'] and i might need to make it into a global variable?

Comment: We cannot fix your code unless you show us. Please, edit your question and provide more information about your problem and include the code that you have.

Comment: Please show your code, its easier to fix your attempt than write a tutorial on how it should be done

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, `$_POST[$row['id']]` makes no sense at all. When there's a new request, $row will not exist any more, that was from the previous request. In your HTML (which it would be helpful if you could show), you would have a hidden field like `<input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="123"/>`. So then when that is submitted, you can check `$_POST["rowID"]` in PHP (because rowID is the name of the hidden field) and its value will be the ID of that row.